# encrypting files in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption, amazon-s3, file-management

I'd like to be able to secure files uploaded by clients.
I haven't really found plug-and-play tools for  Rails apps.
I'd like to use Amazon S3, but their server side encryption is a [joke](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/10/new-amazon-s3-server-side-encryption.html) even though it provides an incremental improvement in security.

Let me define security standards that I find worthwhile if one bothers with encryption:

- make user's password and files invisible (or hardly visible) to the staff

This can be accomplished by storing secure hashes of the password and encryption keys.
One can take the hash in the browser using javascript which is a little bit more secure than doing it inside Rails.

Questions:

Is it worth the hassle of doing hashing and key generation in Javascript? Looks like there are libraries for [hashing](http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/index.html).

If you need to store client's password and/or master key (for file encryption), what would be the approach conceptually?

Are there ruby libraries to do file encryption or do I have to find a way to use [Amazon S3 Java SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/2850096021478074)?